# Created_at nil even after successfully created

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a tracking app and I'm having a weird problem when I try to create a new tracking on my Rails Console.

First, it creates and it can save the "created_at" value, but right after when I place "Tracking.last" it appears with no "created_at" at all.

```
irb(main):005:0> Tracking.create(latitude: 1241214, longitude: 12421412, comment: "testing")

(0.2ms)  BEGIN

Tracking Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "trackings" ("comment", "created_at", "updated_at", "longitude", "latitude") VALUES ($1, 
$2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["comment", "testing"], 
["created_at", "2019-06-13 18:14:57.019001"], ["updated_at", 
"2019-06-13 18:14:57.019001"], ["longitude", 12421412.0], 
["latitude", 1241214.0]]

(0.5ms)  COMMIT

=> #<Tracking id: 3, comment: "testing", created_at: "2019-06-13 
21:14:57", updated_at: "2019-06-13 21:14:57", longitude: 
12421412.0, latitude: 1241214.0>

irb(main):006:0> Tracking.last

Tracking Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "trackings".* FROM "trackings" 
ORDER BY "trackings"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Tracking id: 3, comment: "testing", created_at: nil, 
updated_at: nil, longitude: 12421412.0, latitude: 1241214.0>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try adding `config.active_record.record_timestamps = true`
I don't think this is the problem, but you can test.
This I got from Rails sourcecode in the comments:
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb

Comment: Hi Guilherme. Thanks for the input. Actually the problem was with my timezone setup. I don't know what went wrong but when I delete my timezone setup it works again.